# EXCEL combine multiple vlookup / formulas to reduce columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[SAMPLE - OUTCOME](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0PD0o.jpg)

The sheet is correctly functioning, however looking for a more direct formula to obtain the final column which took a series of formula (columns to the left to achieve it for me).

The rules which make up the formula and give the correct numbers in the Outcome column are:

1. If the code is unique ->Outcome equals Last Digit

2a) For duplicate codes with the same color ->Outcome equals MIN Last Digit

2b) For duplicate codes with multiple color ->Outcome equals MIN Yellow Last Digit

e.g VROW has duplicate codes 1 Yellow 1 Orange -> Outcome is 2 (Yellow Last Digit)

```
D2 =VALUE(RIGHT($B2,1))
E2 =IF(COUNTIF($C3,"<>" & $C2)=1,COUNTIF($C$1:$C1,$C2),"")
F2 ="$A$" & ROW(C2)- (IF(COUNTIF($C3,"<>" & $C2)=1,COUNTIF($C$1:$C1,$C2),"")) & ":$D$" & ROW(C2)
G2 ="$D$" & ROW(C2)- (IF(COUNTIF($C3,"<>" & $C2)=1,COUNTIF($C$1:$C1,$C2),"")) & ":$D$" & ROW(C2)
H2 =IF(C2="","",IFERROR(IFERROR(VLOOKUP("YELLOW",INDIRECT(F2),7,FALSE),MIN(INDIRECT(G2))),H3))
```

| Color | Number | Code | Last Digit | Double # | Vlookup | Min | Outcome |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| YELLOW | Z10635 | ZROW | 5 |  | #VALUE! | #VALUE! | 5 |
| YELLOW | Z10935 | ZROW | 5 | 1 | $A$2:$D$3 | $D$2:$D$3 | 5 |
| YELLOW | Z11966 | WROW | 6 |  | #VALUE! | #VALUE! | 6 |
| YELLOW | Z10179 | WROW | 9 |  | #VALUE! | #VALUE! | 6 |
| YELLOW | Z10276 | WROW | 6 | 2 | $A$4:$D$6 | $D$4:$D$6 | 6 |
| ORANGE | Q02673 | VROW | 3 |  | #VALUE! | #VALUE! | 2 |
| YELLOW | Z10512 | VROW | 2 | 1 | $A$7:$D$8 | $D$7:$D$8 | 2 |
| ORANGE | Q01443 | UROW | 3 |  | #VALUE! | #VALUE! | 0 |
| ORANGE | Q0180 | UROW | 0 | 1 | $A$9:$D$10 | $D$9:$D$10 | 0 |
| YELLOW | Z10319 | TROW | 9 |  | #VALUE! | #VALUE! | 4 |
| YELLOW | Z10074 | TROW | 4 |  | #VALUE! | #VALUE! | 4 |
| YELLOW | Z10244 | TROW | 4 | 2 | $A$11:$D$13 | $D$11:$D$13 | 4 |
| YELLOW | Z10162 | SROW | 2 |  | #VALUE! | #VALUE! | 2 |
| ORANGE | Q02253 | SROW | 3 | 1 | $A$14:$D$15 | $D$14:$D$15 | 2 |

Comment: If you provide your data as a table within your question - it is much easier help you as we only have to copy the values -use e.g.  [Markdown Table Generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables)

Comment: Apologies, completely new to this

Comment: Are there only these two colors? Is it always the case that for multiple colors there is a yellow?

Comment: Yes only ORANGE and YELLOW. No there could be multiple ORANGE with no YELLOW. In which case it is the lowest ORANGE Last Digit. The YELLOW always overrules the ORANGE if they both exist with the same code.

Comment: But could there be RED and ORANGE and no YELLOW?

Comment: No it is just ORANGE and YELLOW (I mistyped RED previously, apologies). And yes it could be all ORANGE or all YELLOW or both (in which case YELLOW rules)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have Excel 365 you can use this `LET`-formul which rebuilds kind of your helper columns:

```vb
=LET(cntCodes,COUNTIF([Code],[@Code]),
cntColors,ROWS(UNIQUE(FILTER([Color],[Code]=[@Code]))),
lastDigits,RIGHT([Number],1),
IF(cntCodes=1,FILTER(lastDigits,[Code]=[@Code]),
       IF(cntColors = 1,INDEX(SORT(FILTER(lastDigits,[Code]=[@Code])),1),
               INDEX(SORT(FILTER(lastDigits,([Code]=[@Code])*([Color]="YELLOW"))),1))))
```

As you can see, I am using a table - then it is easier to reference the columns.

If you don't know about the new formulas, e.g. `UNIQUE` and `FILTER` you propably have to read about them first.

The `IF` part checks your conditions.
You might be wondering why I used `INDEX(SORT(FILTER` instead of `MIN`: `MIN` doesn't work with the `lastDigits` variable :-(

[image]

Comment: Did you format your data as table? (Insert > table)? Do you have Excel 365?

Comment: Thank you. Had to convert it into a table for the code to work. Appreciate your insight. Ill have to look into these new formulas which I only just found out about yesterday.

Comment: It's really worth learning to use them! They make Excel-live a lot easier :-)